# Why can't we just use arrays instead of varargs?

Tags: java, android, arrays, variadic-functions

I just came across `varargs` while learning android(`doInBackground(Type... params)`) ,*SO* posts clarified the use of it

My question is why can't we just use Arrays instead of `varargs`

```
public void foo(String...strings) {  }
```

I can replace this type of a call by packing my variable number of arguments in an array and passing it to a method such as this

```
public void foo(String[] alternativeWay){  }
```

Also does `main(String[] args)` in java use `varargs` , if not how are we able to pass runtime parameters to it

Please suggest the benefits or use of `varargs` and is there there anything else important to know about `varargs`

Comment: Varargs is a syntactic convenience. Before varargs we used to write array creation expressions in long-hand.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you please elaborate and what about main?

Comment: You can declare `main(String... args)` if you like. It won't make any difference.

Comment: As Marko said, it's just syntactic sugar.  Read the docs - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only difference between

```
foo(String... strings)
```

and

```
foo(String[] strings)
```

is for the *calling* code. Consider this call:

```
foo("a", "b");
```

That's valid with the first declaration of `foo`, and the compiler will emit code to create an array containing references to `"a"` and `"b"` at execution time. It's *not* valid with the second declaration of `foo` though, because that doesn't use varargs.

In either case, it's fine for the caller to *explicitly* create the array:

```
for(new String[] { "a", "b" }); // Valid for either declaration
```

> Also does main(String[] args) in java use varargs , if not how are we able to pass runtime parameters to it

When it's written as `main(String[] args)` it doesn't; if you write `main(String... args)` then it does. It's irrelevant to how the JVM treats it though, because the **JVM initialization creates an array with the command line arguments**. It would only make a difference if you were writing your own code to invoke `main` explicitly.

Comment: And you can call it with no arguments as well.

Comment: @popovitsj: Yes, although that will end up creating an empty array.

Comment: ...as you can call the second form with an array of length 0 - but it's much more typing effort :)

Comment: Ok!,the 'Can even be called with no arguments' part sounds neater than calling with a array[0]

Comment: @DroidIcs: Well it's exactly the same thing - it's just "you specify the elements you want in the array, instead of creating the array explicitly."

Comment: there is another difference: varargs must be the last method argument

Comment: One more difference not mentioned is, varargs is always considered last in case of method (name) overloading. E.g. if the argument list is empty and method `foo()` exists, it will be selected, rather than the varargs one. Same goes with `long` or Integer rather than `int...` when there is one arg. In case of heavy overloading, the substitution might not be as easy as suggested.

Answer (score 5):

We could use arrays instead of varargs. Varargs are syntactic sugar for using arrays. But they make your code more compact and more readable. Compare

```
private void foo(String... ss) { ... }

private void bar() {
    ...
    foo("One", "Two", "Three");
    ...
}
```

with

```
private void foo(String[] ss) { ... }

private bar() {
    ...
    foo(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
    ...
}
```

Similarly, we don't need the diamond operator (<>, Java 7) or lambdas (Java 8) either. But they do make code more readable and therefore more maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

One advantage of varargs is for methods requiring at least one parameter, such as `max`. With varargs you can do it like this

```
static int max(int first, int... remaining) {
    int max = first;
    for (int number : remaining)
        max = Math.max(max, number);
    return max;
}
```

This is great, because it is *impossible* to pass no parameters to the `max` method, and the calling code for `max` is really clean: `max(2, 4, 1, 8, 9)`. Without varargs the only way to have enforced the condition that at least one number should be passed would have been to have thrown an exception at runtime if the array had length 0 (always best avoided) or to force the caller to write `max(2, new int[] {4, 1, 8, 9})` which is really ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Because you function call looks more like a function call, ex.:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute("str1", "str2");
```

looks better than:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(new String[]{"str1", "str2"});
```

There is no magic behind `AsyncTask`, very often you dont really need to pass any parameters, sometimes you pass parameters to constructor instead of execute. There are also implementations of AsyncTask :

https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/util/SafeAsyncTask.java

that dont use varargs at all